# SVN : Change the version control model

Tags: svn

I am currently working on an SVN deposit that is configured to use "Lock-Modify-Unlock" as its version control model. I need to change that model to the one called "Copy-Modify-Merge", which is, if I understand correctly, the same behaviour as git.

I could not find how to do that... I found [this documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.basic.version-control-basics.html) that explains perfectly what each model does, but that doesn't indicate *how* to configure the deposit...

Is there a property file to change or something in order to configure my deposit ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in configuration switch to change how Subversion works with regard to this. If your repository requires that you lock items to edit them, those items (or, in a scary scenario, every item in the repository, enforced via hook script) has the `svn:needs-lock` property set.

You need to speak with your repository administrator to find out how the repository was set up and if it uses a hook script, ask that individual to revert that hook script. You *might* be able to get away with removing `svn:needs-lock` on items as you work on them, but you need to talk to the administrator first.

There may be a valid reason for your repository being set up this way. Doubtful, but possible.